# un-used URLs in URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

Say I am creating something that loads all jars in an external directory to dynamically add optional functionality to an application.

I iterate over all of the jars in that directory and confirm that they are jars and load them as urls into a URLCLassLoader.

Now that I can load the classes in those jars say I find out one or two of them are not usable by my application.

Is there any large cost in giving a URLClassLoader urls for jars that wont be used?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They will be (a) downloaded, and (b) searched for classes.